# Importing js modules by directory name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm upgrading a React application and have found that I need to modify the import statements to get them to work.

For example, in the old version, the following import works without errors:

```
import { User } from '../System'
```

Note that `System` is a directory on my file system that contains `User`, a js file that ends with `export default User`.

In my upgraded version of the app, the System directory still exists, but the above import gives me **`Can't resolve '../System' in 'C:\my app\`**.

It turns out that to get the import working properly now, I need to change it to the following:

```
import User from '../System/User';
```

If I understand correctly, this relates to js [module system](https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/) changes made with ES6.

My question, though, is regarding the specification of a directory in the import statement (`System` above). Why would it be that I was previously able to name a file directory in the import statement instead of the actual js script/module itself? Is that approach of using a directory in the import statement still possible? And if so, is it ever advisable?

**Update**: based on AKX's comment, I noticed the `System` directory does indeed contain an *index.js*, which apparently is what makes the import from the directory itself possible.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you didn't have `System/index.js` before?

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent question. Looks like the app does in fact have a `System/index.js` which contains import and export statements. I had no idea that was related. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an import points to a directory, and only a file, Webpack (which most React setups use) [follows](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9218#issuecomment-498122499) [Node's's conventions](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together) and will attempt to import `index.js` from that directory if it exists. That's the only condition under which importing from a path that points to a directory works - your previous build probably had `/System/index.js` (which would allow importing with `from '../System'`). If you rename the file you're importing to anything else - such as to `User.js` - importing using only the directory path will fail.

> And if so, is it ever advisable?

Sure, if you want. It's a style choice but is commonly done.